# jQuery-UI upgrade introduced error in code that worked previously

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a simple jQuery routine for drag/drop, I recently upgraded from 1.7.2 to 1.8.21 and now when I drop the items, I get the error message 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'search' of undefined'

Couldn't find anything through search, so I'm hoping someone has seen this one before.

Here's the code:

```
$("#frame").droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        if (ui.helper.attr('id').search(/drag[0-9]/) != -1){
            counter++;
            var element=$(ui.draggable).clone();
            element.addClass("tempclass");
            $(this).append(element);
            $(".tempclass").attr("id","sig_"+counter);
            //$(this).css('z-index', 100+counter);
            $("#sig_"+counter).removeClass("tempclass");
            var x = event.pageX - $(this).offset().left + 4;
            var y = event.pageY - $(this).offset().top + 4;
            $(this).find("input").val(x+","+y);
            $("div#stop").text("STOP: \nLeft: "+ x + "\nTop: " + y);
            //Get the dynamically item id
            draggedNumber = ui.helper.attr('id').search(/drag([0-9])/)
            itemDragged = "dragged" + RegExp.$1
            //console.log(itemDragged)

            $("#sig_"+counter).addClass(itemDragged);
        }
    }
});
```

jQuery Version: 1.7.2
jQuery-UI Version: 1.8.21
Browser: Chrome 20.0.1132

UPDATE: I seem to have found something that 'works', but I don't feel it's proper as I'm using a pre-existing item. (I tried copying, but that didn't work.) I changed two lines, both containing the same code that fails:

```
ui.helper.attr('id')
```

to

```
ui.draggable.attr('id')
```

I suppose this would only work in my specific case, and possibly should have included the 'draggable' block as well but it works for the moment.

Comment: Have you checked deprecated for functions?

Comment: I checked the upgrade guide [here](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Upgrade_Guide). No luck. Is there another resource for dep'd functions?